# Unable to insert comments into MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Unable to insert data into MySQL database even though the connection seems okay and I am not receiving any errors from my page or the server and I've verified that my database credentials are correct. The comments are not showing up in the database at all and just basically disappear when I click submit. I've been doing my best but I'm still confused. If someone could take a look it would be most appreciated.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
include '../conn/dba.inc.php';
include '../function/comments.inc.php'; 
?>

<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>   
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<Title>Test</Title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/default.css"> 

</head>
<body onLoad="document.forms.Mfrm.message.focus()">
<?php
echo
"<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."' name='Mfrm'>
<input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
<input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:m')."'>  
<input type='text' class='inptcss' name='message' placeholder='Placeholder'/>
<button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
</form><br>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

comments.inc.php

```
<?php
function setComments($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid,date,message) 
        VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        }
}
?>
```

dba.inc.php (When I run this I get the response "Database Is Selected")

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "123456789_username";
$password = "dbpassword";
$dbname = "123456789_db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);} 

if(!$conn)
{echo'Not Connected To Server';}

if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'$dbname'))
 {echo'Database Is Not Selected';}

if(mysqli_select_db($conn,'$dbname'))
 {echo'Database is Selected';}
?>
```

Here is the code used to create the table in my database:

```
    CREATE TABLE comments (
     cid int(11) not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     uid varchar(128) not null,
     date datetime not null,
     message TEXT not null);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `action='".setComments($conn)."'` what is this supposed to do?

Comment: The `action` attribute of a `<form>` needs to be a URI string. Typically, this would be the URL of your `.php` file that handles the form submission, eg `action="add-comment.php"`

Comment: Also, please read about prepared statements and parameter binding ~ http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Your code shows that you don't have a good understanding on how [Form Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) works and [how to use mysqli properly](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). Read the tutorials provided by those two links and rewrite your code.